# Eclipse not generating files in new Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse

I´ve got a problem with Eclipse. Everytime I try to start a new Android Project in Eclipse (both Juno and Indigo) 64b on Ubuntu, nothing is created besides the directories. No files in src, res etc, no xmls, no .java. I've set the location of the SDK correctly.

I tried to:
reinstall sdk, with less API
install ADT fo a few times, yes it is installed
change the Eclipse version
check the Java version on PC

but nothing works

Here are some printscreens, how the situation looks like when I´m clicking Next on New Android App window. Nothing´s changing, only window titles.

http://imageshack.us/g/69/screenshotnewandroidapp.png/

Thx for help!;)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

check in the Java build path library, whether src check box is checked or not.